# Grok expression to Parse Log data

Tags: logstash-grok, grok

I have just started using grok for logstash and I am trying to parse my log file line below using grok filter.

**10.210.57.60 0x756682x2 connectadmin [12/May/2020:00:00:00 +0530] "GET /rest/auth/1/session HTTP/1.1" 200 286 456 "-" "Jersey/2.11 (HttpUrlConnection 1.8.0_171)" "1twyrho"**

I am interested in : 
IP : 10.210.57.60 //
user : connectadmin //
timestamp : 12/May/2020:00:00:00 +0530 //
URL : /rest/auth/1/session //
Response Code   : 200

I am currently stuck with the grok expression : **%{IPV4:client_ip} %{WORD:skip_me1} %{USERNAME}**
by which I am able to get IP and username. Can you please help me proceed.

Thank You..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used grok debugger https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ to get the desired output.
Below is the grok pattern that will match your requirement:

```
%{IPV4:IP} %{GREEDYDATA:girbish} %{USERNAME:user} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] "(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})" %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) %{GREEDYDATA:girbish}
```

Also, below is the screenshot of final output after using the grok pattern

[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]
[image: screenshot3]

**Note:** You can remove unnecessary fields using mutate filter of logstash.